# API - Microsoft Cognitive Services Face, how to return attributes

Tags: ios, swift, azure-cognitive-services

In swift I'm using the Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API function `detectWithData` and trying to use `returnFaceAttributes` which calls for `[AnyObject]!`. I need help with what to enter into the Array.

According to [this link](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) I assumed `["age", "gender"]` would work but I receive an error saying:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b96043df0

And using `[MPOFaceAttributeTypeAge, MPOFaceAttributeTypeGender]` gives an error:

> Value of type 'MPOFaceAttributeTypeAge' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'

For some reason typing "true" in the array give me the age attribute but all other attributes show as nil.

I can't find any examples using swift online.  Any advice or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
@IBAction func battleBtn(sender: UIButton){
    if !hasChoosenTop || !hasChoosenBottom{
        showErrorAlert()
    } else{
        if let firstImg = topImg.image, let firstImgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(firstImg, 0.8), let secondImg = bottomImg.image, let secondImgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(secondImg, 0.8){
            FaceService.instance.client.detectWithData(firstImgData, returnFaceId: true, returnFaceLandmarks: false, returnFaceAttributes: [MPOFaceAttributeTypeAge, MPOFaceAttributeTypeGender], completionBlock: { (face: [MPOFace]!, err: NSError!) in
                if err == nil {
                    var topFace: String?
                    topFace = face[0].faceId
                    var top = face[0].attributes.age
                    print("my faceId: \(topFace)")
                    print("my faceId: \(top)")

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1tCL.png)

Comment: Please include your code as text, not picture

Comment: thanks, edited question

Answer (score 1):

Include an array of Int for `[AnyObject]!`.  For example: `[1,4]` returns age and smile.